Between jobs, but have affiliations with multiple organizations
I don't have an academic home base, but I am an affiliate or external associate academic member of several academic research groups (listed on their website, etc).  I plan to join one of these full time in a few months.  Would it make sense for me to list it as my current affiliation on publications?

You "plan" to join them. But it may be up to them whether you can or not.
However, if the typical review time for these publications once submitted is longer than a "few months", then it matters little what you list on the initial submission. There will be opportunities for updates.
And, not that if the work for the publications is supported in any way by one or the other of these organizations, it might be necessary to list them as your affiliation, provided they agree.
Most important, an affiliation is a joint decision. You might ask the one you are planning on joining if they have any objections. I doubt there would be a problem if they already list you.
Whether or not the organization has given you an email address might be a (minor) consideration.


I am an affiliate or external associate academic member of several
academic research groups


Would it make sense for me to list it as my current affiliation on
publications?

Yes (assuming your affiliation is official, in whatever sense).
